# Recoil Effect is behaving strange

Tags: reactjs, recoiljs

I am new to recoil. I have just built an example form that have 2 buttons. One for decreasing and one for increasing a counter.

I just added an effect to see how it is working but for some reason this effect only happens when I am decreasing the counter and I have no idea why

```js
export const counterState = new atom({
    key: 'counter',
    default: 0,
    effects: [({onSet, setSelf}) => {
        onSet((newCounter, oldCounter) => {
            console.log(`The new counter is ${newCounter}, the old one is ${oldCounter}`);
            setSelf(newCounter - 1);
        });
    }]
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Very weird. I tested it in my local project, and I can see the same issue. But It's ok when I removed `-1` in setSelf.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).